# nested serialization dont now create a forignkey it requires a new Object instead of 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

here is my model, serializer and output but when i want to create a new page it ask me to add a whole new user as its just a foreign-key it need to be a number like 1 (user id) and same in the case of categories  how can i solve it.... help me please

### serializers.py

```
class TeamMembersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TeamMembers
        fields = [
            'user',
            'page',
        ]
        depth = 1

class SocialAccountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    social = SocialCatSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = SocialAccounts
        fields = [
            'page',
            'social',
            'link'
        ]
        depth = 1

class PageImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PageImages
        fields = [
            'page',
            'image',
        ]
        depth = 1

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    catagory = BusinessCatSerializers()
    business_type = BusinessTypeSerializer()
    TeamMembers = TeamMembersSerializer(read_only=True)
    social_accounts = SocialAccountsSerializer(read_only=True)
    images = PageImageSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model =Page
        fields = [
            'id',
            'owner',
            'catagory',
            'name',
            'username',
            'images',
            'start_date',
            'business_type',
            'contect_number',
            'email_address',
            'website',
            'TeamMembers',
            'social_accounts',
            'about',
            'impression',
            'Awards',
            'Product',
            'privacy_policy',
            'is_active',
        ]
```

---

Models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    catagory = models.ForeignKey(BusinessCatagories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True ,default=None, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    business_type = models.ForeignKey(BusinessType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    contect_number = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=None, blank=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField(default=None, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True)
    impression = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True)
    Awards = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=None, blank=True)
    Product = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=None, blank=True)
    privacy_policy = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    page =  models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name

class SocialAccounts(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    social = models.ForeignKey(SocialCats, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link

class PageImages(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default=None, blank=True, upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page.name
```

---

output is this but i need images field TeamMember field in it but its not appearing plus it want me to add a new user instead of asking for Foreignkey "id"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the *code* itself, not *images* of code.

Comment: Here it is.... Now plz help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use Primary key related field. It helps you to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key.

It should look somewhat like this.
Note: Mind the typo for any name

```html
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = User.objects.all())
    catagory = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = BuisnessCat.objects.all())
    business_type = BusinessTypeSerializer()
    TeamMembers = TeamMembersSerializer(read_only=True)
    social_accounts = SocialAccountsSerializer(read_only=True)
    images = PageImageSerializer(read_only=True)
```

You can read more about PrimaryKeyRelatedField [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

Now whenever creating any Page, all you need to supply are primary key for owner and category.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [**Writable Nested Serializer**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).
In short you have to override `create()` method of `PageSerializer`

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....
    ....
    your code
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # pop data of every related fields like "owner", "cateagory" etc from validated_data
        owner = validated_data.pop("owner")
        owner = User.objects.create(**owner)

        category = validated_data.pop("category")
        # create or retrieve category instance ,as above
        ...
        ...
        ...
        # finally
        return Page.objects.create(**validated_data,owner=owner,category=category, and other related instances)
```

Comment: its still the same

Comment: its again giving this error
`{
    "owner": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    },
    "catagory": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    },
    "business_type": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: `    def create(self, validated_data):
        # pop data of every related fields like "owner", "catagory" etc from validated_data
        owner = validated_data.pop("owner")
        owner = User.objects.create(**owner)
        catagory = validated_data.pop("catagory")
        catagory = BusinessCatagories(**catagory)
        business_type = validated_data.pop("business_type")
        business_type = BusinessType(**business_type)
        return Page.objects.create(**validated_data, owner=owner, catagory=catagory, business_type=business_type)`